# Too many methods in HttpServiceFactory interface

Tags: c#, .net

In my controller I have this code which works fine:

```
var service = HttpServiceFactory.CreateService<IMasterDataService>();
return await service.SetCurrency(pCurrencyDto);
```

If I add a new method declaration (correctly) to IMasterDataServiceDefinition interface which is implemented is IMasterDataService, I get the following error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'MethodHelper_47636508.ServiceDefinitions.MasterData.IMasterDataService' threw an exception. --->
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

I think there could be a method limitation somewhere in the interface or in the HttpServiceFactory.

Can you help please to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: The error might be from different part of the code then you've created. The best would be to check the stack of the call and see where it gets invoked. If you have no idea what to do next, maybe you can provide code for the implementation class that implements the interface `IMasterDataService` and we could go from there.

Comment: why do you think there´s a limit for functions in an interface?